# Enumerable Qt widgets

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have a Qt dialog box with several controls that need more or less uniform processing. I want to store pointers to them in an array and enumerate over them.

In Windows, I'd use sequential control IDs and `GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_BASEID + i)` in a loop. In Cocoa, i'd use sequential view tags or include them in an invisible container. What's the Qt way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reach iteratively few variables which names differ only by number in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566603/how-to-reach-iteratively-few-variables-which-names-differ-only-by-number-in-c)

Comment: Please see my answer to the linked question, I believe that it does what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [QObject::findChildren(QRegExp)](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qobject.html#findChildren-2) can do the trick if the widgets have similar names.

```
QList<QLineEdit*> lineEdits = dialog->findChildren<QLineEdit*>(QRegExp("lineEdit[0-9]+"));
foreach (QLineEdit* lineEdit, lineEdits) {
    lineEdit->clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The dupe answer tells you how to do this - but you probably shouldn't

The Qt way is to have the same slot (ie handler) registered for all the widgets - then in the event handler use the field in the event to tell you which widget fired and get a pointer to it.

Comment: Multiplexing signal processing is easily done via QSignalMapper (note: signals, not events). However, doing the same for properties needs enumeration of some kind. Think "Clear all"-type operations - where's the slot in that?

Comment: Ok - if you want to enable, or populate a list of widgets then a vector of pointers might be a good solution. Iterating over them to see which was pressed isn't.